# CURL error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Tags: php, ssl, curl, web-scraping, proxy

I'm trying to use proxy and SSL certificate with `CURL`, But I get errors.

Here is the `CURL` code:

```
//Website
$url = 'https://www.stubhub.com';

//Curl
$curl=curl_init();

//SSL
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'C:\xampp\cacert.pem' );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL,trim( $url ) );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36' );

//Proxy
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, '177.190.147.241:41545');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_PORT , 80);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,__DIR__."/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $vbh );
```

I get the following response:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.stubhub.com/
*   Trying 177.190.147.241...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 177.190.147.241 (177.190.147.241) port 41545 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to www.stubhub.com:80
> CONNECT www.stubhub.com:80 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.stubhub.com:80
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< 
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\xampp\cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* Closing connection 0
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.stubhub.com/
```

You are trying to reach the URL `https://www.stubhub.com/` - which means the given host on port 443 (default for https) with protocol https (i.e. HTTP over TLS).

But, for unknown reasons you explicitly specify that port 80 should be used instead of port 443:

```
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_PORT , 80);
```

This means it will not connect to the host on port 443 but on port 80:

```
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to www.stubhub.com:80
> CONNECT www.stubhub.com:80 HTTP/1.1
```

Port 80 is for plain HTTP. Nevertheless the client will try https (HTTP over TLS) since this is what the URL said. The client will thus try to initiate a TLS handshake by sending the ClientHello. Since the server expects a plain HTTP request but gets a TLS ClientHello instead it will reply with the HTTP error response. The client then will try to parse this response as the expected TLS response and fail:

```
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

> How to fix this?

Don't set CURLOPT_PORT to 80. Just don't set CURLOPT_PORT so that it is taken from the URL. From the [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PORT.html):

> This option sets number to be the remote port number to connect to, **instead of the one specified in the URL** or the default port for the used protocol. Usually, you **just let the URL decide** which port to use but this allows the application to override that.